# recursion in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, recursion

I am learning Linux command and I am practicing and trying to write a basic shell script which list all the files and files in subfolders, like `ls *`, using recursion.

```
#!/bin/bash

# list-all: one command to list them all!!!!

listit () {
        if [ -d "$1" ]
        then
                listit "$1"
        else
                echo "$1"
        fi  
}

ls | while read items; do
        listit "$items"
done
```

However, the result shows:

```
./list-all: line 16:  1101 Done                    ls
      1102 Segmentation fault: 11  | while read items; do
    listit "$items";
done
```

Is that because shell doesn't allow recursion? please help, thank you!

Comment: +1 to you for your learning efforts. Are you aware of `ls -R` or `find . type -f`?

Comment: @glennjackman, Thank you! I just realized you can use these commands. Though for the second one, I think it should be `find . -type f`

Comment: Indeed, thanks for spotting the typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shell certainly supports recursion. But your function takes arguments, and you're passing it stdin. Besides that, you really shouldn't be [parsing the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Consider this:

```bash
listit() {
    while [ "$1" ]; do
        if [ -d "$1" ]; then
            listit "$1"/*
        else
            printf '%s\n' "$1"
        fi
        shift
    done
}

listit *
```

If you really want to read stdin, you'd have to rewrite `listit` to do that. That's tricky, since you only get one standard input, and each recursive call would try to own it. Filenames are a simple thing accessible as arguments through globbing, so I'd stick to that.

Answer (score 2):

You overflowed the stack with an infinite recursion. Consider calling `listit /`.

The first `if` will see that `/` is a directory so it will call `listit /` which will then call `listit /` ...

See [this answer for what happens next](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16819744/282912).